Mailcatcher HTTP/1 is not supported
I am using Mailcatcher when doing testing with codeception in an Github Actions.
Installing it like this:
  - name: Install & run mailcatcher
    run: |
      sudo gem install mailcatcher --no-update-sources --no-document
      mailcatcher

In the acceptance.suite.yml the config is:
modules:
  enabled:
    - Asserts
    - Helper\Acceptance
    - DbHelper
    - Filesystem
    - MailCatcher
  config:
    MailCatcher:
      url: "http://127.0.0.1"
      port: "1080"
      guzzleRequestOptions:
        verify: false
        debug: false
        version: 1.0

Since yesterday when doing this:
$I->resetEmails();

I get this error message:
[GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException] HTTP/1 is not supported by the cURL handler.  

Nothing has changed...?

Your error is being raised Here but I don't understand php well enough to full grasp the call stack. It is unclear specifically what is causing the error at the moment but many of the recent changes to guzzle revolve around cURL handlers.

What solved the issue here was removing the version: 1.0 line in guzzleRequestOptions.
